# EF 4.1 DBContext AutoDetectChangesEnabled

Tags: entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

OK. I have turned off AutoDetectChangesEnabled, and when I query the context, modify an entity and attempt to save changes, nothing gets updated. I would expect that.

But when I mark the entity as modified, I would expect it to change.

Any ideas?

I am using the UnitOfWork, Repository, Service pattern.

If I enable AutoDetectChangesEnabled then all is fine.

What is the standard way to persist changes to attached objects?

What about detached objects?

Thanks in advance,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just entities what is tracked, but relations as well.

```
ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager
      .ChangeRelationshipState(resolution, resolution.Message, r => r.Message, EntityState.Added);
```