# How can I stop EF detecting changes to my database / model

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following in my code:

```
 DbContext = new DataContext();
 DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

Then in my controller method:

```
// GET /api/Applications
public IEnumerable<Application> Get()
{
    return _uow.Applications.GetAll().OrderBy(p => p.Name);
}
```

However I still get the following message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The model backing the 'DataContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
```

Can someone explain why this is happening. I thought the line after my context creation would stop this check.

Comment: Why can't you update the database ?

Comment: I'm not trying to update. I am trying to get data and it's complaining that my model has changed. However I thought with the auto detect changes set to false that it would not do that check. That's what i don't understand.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Models and database should be in sync for entity framework to work. If you want to exclude property from being visible to EF, just annotate it with [NotMapped].

Answer (score 9):

You can place (it's a static method)

```
Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(null);
```

before you first use your `DataContext`. But take a note, that this will turn it off. Done. If your database is not compatible with model, your queries etc. will fail.

Comment: Better than having your database replaced.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have some difference in database schema with your entity mode.  The error is saying that you need to update the database schema according to the new model you have in the code.

**AutoDetectChangesEnabled**  is [not something related to this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977609/ef-4-1-dbcontext-autodetectchangesenabled). Because it is about tracking changes to the data while the error you are getting is related to the changes in database schema .

The error message is suggesting you to use [code first migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621) to update the database schema according to your changes in data model.

Comment: you can manually update the database or you can use DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges initializer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793184/how-to-recreate-database-in-ef-if-my-model-changes

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:
**1. Set the Initializer of your context to `null` by placing this line in the constructor of your derived DbContext:**

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
```

**2. Disable the Database Initializer in your `Web.config` file by adding a `Key` inside the `appSettings` node:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>    
    <add key="DatabaseInitializerForType YourNamespace.YourDbContext, YourAssemblyName"
            value="Disabled" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Replace `YourNamespace.YourDbContext` and `YourAssemblyName` with the corresponding value in your application.